# Ethereum node stops automatically

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I have deployed an Ethereum node on my VPS server. I am starting node sync using:

```
geth --syncmode light console --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal
```

But after few hours it stops automatically. How can I solve this problem? Please can you shade some light on this?

Comment: Does it log any errors when it closes?

Comment: Logs is something that can help to debug.

Comment: @Henk
No..There was no any error and stops automatically after 3 to 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that your problem is related to which ports are open. Be sure to open port 30303 (or your discovery port) so that other nodes can find you and so that you have as many peers as possible.